# VSIX - Show popup for long running operation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

In a VSIX Visual Studio extension we would like to execute a long running operation (3-4 sec). When Visual Studio itself does such actions, they show a popup to indicate that to the user, and give the possibility to cancel it.

Does somebody know how we can do the same in our own extension (showing a popup while executing the action)? I know that it would be better to run it in a separate thread, but in this case it's almost impossible.

Comment: A Tool window appears to respond to some specific event?

Comment: Run action in separate thread. Show popup window in main thread and invoke progress to this window from background thread.

Comment: Can you clarify where exactly you've encountered this feature. What was displayed in the popup, and what particular action invoked the dialog?  Knowing the details, we maybe able to point you to specific examples that do the same thing.